# Adding fragment's chain in the stack using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have a pet project where I am using Android Architecture Component. So it's a single activity with few fragments. I'm using Navigation Component and it's working fine. But now I want to open a specific fragment from a notification. But also I want to add the previous fragment to the backstack .

So if I have a fragment C which is usually opened from a fragment B. I want to open app (from notification) in fragment's sequence A->B->C  In that way, when I press "back-button" I will close the fragment C and I will see the fragment B (but not main fragment A). Is it possible to achieve this using NavigationComponent?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with explicit deep links inside Navigation graph. I never work with that myself, but as I read the documentation you can achieve just what you are describing. Proper back navigation as if you would navigate to that screen through the app.

> When a user opens your app via an explicit deep link, the task back stack is cleared and replaced with the deep link destination. When nesting graphs, the start destination from each level of nesting—that is, the start destination from each  element in the hierarchy—is also added to the stack. This means that when a user presses the Back button from a deep link destination, they navigate back up the navigation stack just as though they entered your app from its entry point.

SOURCE: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#explicit